# React-Native: How to create more than one instance of a Native UI component?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native

It says on the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html that "ViewManagers are singleton objects"

If this is so, how would I create another instance of my UI object - Say for example on another screen.

Here are small snippets of my code:

js:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

var DataViewNative = requireNativeComponent('DataView', myClass);

class myClass extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DataViewNative {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

myClass.propTypes = {
  graphType: PropTypes.string,
};

module.exports = myClass;
```

native ios (swift):

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(DataViewManager, RCTViewManager)

@end


@objc(DataViewManager)
class DataViewManager: RCTViewManager {

  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return myCustomView()
  }

}
```

What I want to be able to do (js):
Call:

```
 <myClass/>
```

in two different render() methods on two different screens.
What happens is that since RCTViewManager is a singleton object, the call to view() replaces the old call, therefore only the most recent call to  will have the UIView

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my "simplified version" that I wrote in my question was actually the answer. This is my original (not working) code :

```
var view  = MyCustomView()

override func view() -> UIView! {
  return view
}
```

Which goes against the documentation at:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26d3af3421f0768cc2d4aeb354068ace3f7581e3/React/Views/RCTViewManager.h#L35-L42